# What are the differences between Configuration and Developer Sandboxes?

Tags: sandbox

The [Sandbox Documentation](https://na7.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/create_test_instance.htm) describes Configuration and Developer sandboxes, but it's hard to tell what's actually different about them:

> **Configuration Only Sandbox**
>
> Configuration-only sandboxes copy all of your production organization's reports, dashboards, price books, products, apps, and customizations under Your Name | Setup, but exclude all of your organization's standard and custom object records, documents, and attachments. Creating a configuration-only sandbox can decrease the time it takes to create or refresh a sandbox from several hours to just a few minutes, but it can only include up to 500 MB of data. You can refresh a configuration-only sandbox once per day.
>
> **Developer Sandbox**
>
> Developer sandboxes are special configuration-only sandboxes intended for coding and testing by a single developer. Multiple users can log into a single developer sandbox, but their primary purpose is to provide an environment in which changes under active development can be isolated until they’re ready to be shared. Just like configuration-only sandboxes, developer sandboxes copy all application and configuration information to the sandbox. Developer sandboxes are limited to 10 MB of test or sample data, which is enough for many development and testing tasks. You can refresh a developer sandbox once per day.

Aside from the difference in data capacity (500 MB for Configuration Only, 10 MB for Developer), what are the differences between these two Sandbox types?

Comment: I think that is the only difference.

Comment: That is the only difference.

Comment: There's the money thing, too.  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that is the only difference. As Mohith points out in [his answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4356/142), the difference in data limits has practical implications for how various sandboxes are used.

Answer (score 6):

Use **configuration** only sandbox if we want to configure and develop an application which involves multiple developer working on the development and configuration of app .Data limit is 500MB which is good amount to test the app with considerable amount of data

As said use **developer** only if you want to isolate any module and develop with single developer assigned .Later when the module is ready we merge with other modules .Data is limited to 10MB.This is a very rare scenario when we think of assigning single module and asking single developer to work on it and then merge those changes .

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the capacity limit - 500 for config and 10 for developer

Answer (score 1):

Sandboxes come in in several flavors, including *Developer*, *Developer Pro*, *Partial Data*, and *Full* Sandboxes. Each one has a specialized purpose (and corresponding cost). Developer Editions, in contrast, have two editions, *Normal Developer Edition* and *ISV Developer Edition*.

Here's what you need to know:

- Sandbox editions can copy fields, objects, and users from their sponsor organization. Developer editions do not have a sponsor and therefore cannot automatically copy data to and from any other organization.
- Developer editions can support Managed Packages suitable for AppExchange listings (upgradeable, intellectual property-protected code), while Sandboxes do not support this type of package.
- Sandbox editions can copy data automatically (depending on type), while developer editions will always start with a set of stock data.

In summary, Sandbox editions are for testing proposed changes to *your* organization, and developer editions are suited to uploading AppExchange apps and independent test or learning environments. It's easy to tell the two apart, too: Sandboxes have a unique URL to login at.

Answer (score 1):

2 Basic differences are

i)   Data capacity    Developer: 200 MB             Developer Pro/Config: 500 MB
 ii)  Cost             Developer: aprox 10% of Prod  Developer Pro/Config: aprox 20% of prodProduction