# Which Sandbox Types are Configuration-Only?

Tags: sandbox-refresh, partial-sandbox

This [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4355/what-are-the-differences-between-configuration-and-developer-sandboxes/4356#4356) asks what the difference is between configuration and developer sandboxes, but I want to know which sandbox types are configuration-only.  In no documentation are certain types called out as configuration-only.

I need to know because these release [notes](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/184/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_summer13_release_notes.pdf) say *custom settings data is now copied to Developer and Configuration Only sandboxes*, and we're about to refresh a partial-copy sandbox.

If custom settings are going to be copied, my task is to write a refresh script that reloads the sandbox's custom-settings data over and against production's.  If not, then I obviously don't need to bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial and Full sandboxes already copy Custom Settings. Configuration-only Sandboxes refer to Developer and Developer Pro sandboxes. Previously, you had to manually migrate Custom Settings to those two types of Sandboxes, but this is no longer true. Note that "Configuration Only" sandboxes, as noted in the previous question, have been rebranded as Developer Pro (there is no such thing as a "Configuration Only" sandbox these days).